# Firebase: Error (auth/user-token-expired)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

let me first note that I am new to firebase and authentication matters ... for several days I am facing a problem with updating email and password functionality using firebase... I want to know if this problem have something with using React and its way of working like re-rendering components ..etc. or is it the use of promises the way i've done in the code below.. I really don't know.

## This is the error that I am facing.

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/user-token-expired).

## Here is the code involved in the situation

#### firebase.js

```
const updateUserEmail = (newEmail) => {
        return updateEmail(auth.currentUser, newEmail);
}
const updateUserPassword = (newPassword) => {
        return updatePassword(auth.currentUser, newPassword);
}
```

#### update_profile.jsx

```
async function handleUpdateProfile() {
      setErrorMessage('');
      setIsLoading(true);
      // check for password equality
      if (passwordInputRef.current.value !== confirmPasswordInputRef.current.value) {
        setErrorMessage('Passwords do not match');
        return;
      }
      const promises = [];
      if (emailInputRef.current.value !== currentUser?.email) {

     promises.push(updateUserEmail(emailInputRef.current.value));
     
      }
      
      if (passwordInputRef) {
 promises.push(updateUserPassword(passwordInputRef.current.value);

      }
 
      Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        navigate('/');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(currentUser);
        console.log(err)
        setErrorMessage('Couldn\'t Update Your Profile');
      }).finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
    }
```

I tried auth.currentUser.reload()
like that

```
auth.currentUser.reload().then(() => {
        updateEmail(auth.currentUser, newEmail);
    })
```

I tried Re-authenticate the user using the doc guide here
[firebaseDocs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

but nothing solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I have come to an answer for my question that has worked**
I am not quite sure, but I believe that the root of my problem returns to two things

1. Reauthentication of a user
2. Async matters

Here is how I solved the error

#### firebase.js

```
const updateUserEmail = async (newEmail) => {
    const email = prompt('Please Enter Your Email');
    const password = prompt('Please enter your password');
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
    await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential).then(() => {
        updateEmail(auth.currentUser, newEmail);
    })    
   
}
const updateUserPassword = async (newPassword) => {
    const email = prompt('Please Enter Your Email');
    const password = prompt('Please enter your password');
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
    await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential).then(() => {
        updatePassword(auth.currentUser, newPassword);
    })   
}
```

for each update I prompted the user to give me his email and pass, and then used it for reauthenticating matters.
to fix the async issue.. i made the function to wait for the first update (email) before proceeding to the next update (password) and the next lines of code clarify it more.

#### update_profile.jsx

```
      let newEmail = false;
      let newPassword = false;
      if (emailInputRef.current.value !== currentUser?.email) {
         newEmail = true;
      }  
      if (passwordInputRef) {
        newPassword = true;
      }
    
      if (newEmail) {
        await updateUserEmail(emailInputRef.current.value);
        if (newPassword) {
          await updateUserPassword(passwordInputRef.current.value);
        }
      }
```

I bet there are better solutions than mine and I'll be happy to read it, but for now this will do the trick.